# Create helm chart using image from local harbor

Tags: image, kubernetes-helm, minikube, harbor

I have created a `NestJs` app, packaged it into a bin-file using `pkg`, containerized it with docker image and name it `projectABC`. All of these were deployed in Ubuntu20 and the bin file runs perfectly fine.

Next, i wanted to try [harbor](https://goharbor.io/) repository. Following the [tutorial](https://goharbor.io/docs/1.10/install-config/), i created local harbor repository with self-signed certificate with this [tut](https://goharbor.io/docs/1.10/working-with-projects/working-with-images/pulling-pushing-images/#pushing-images). I am using `minikube` to deploy harbor in my machine.

After harbor is up, i created a project with name "project", then pushed the `projectABC` image into it with `Project registry` set to `Public`. All is well from `docker login`, `docker tag`, to `docker push`. Testing the newly pushed image, i can `docker pull` and check the `projectABC` run as intended.

So now I want to deploy using [helm](https://helm.sh/) chart. So far i have successfully login into registry and pushed an empty chart project.

```sh
helm create projectABC
export HELM_EXPERIMENTAL_OCI=1
helm chart save ./projectABC 192.168.1.69/project/ABC
helm registry login https://192.168.1.69 --insecure
helm chart push 192.168.1.69/project/ABC:0.0.1
```

Then i modified `values.yaml` to pull the image from harbor repo

```sh
image:
  repository: 192.168.1.69/project/ABC:0.0.1
  pullPolicy: Always
```

But it failed with result:
`container in pod is waiting to start: trying and failing to pull image`

So my questions:

1. How do i register my local-harbor as a repo in helm?
2. Does my local-harbor considered as a private or public repo?
3. What should i do to let my chart pull an image from my local-harbor repo?

Comment: i tried to add repo using `helm repo add local https://192.168.1.69/project --insecure-skip-tls-verify`, failed with error message: `looks like "https://192.168.1.69/project" is not a valid chart repository or cannot be reached: error unmarshaling JSON: while decoding JSON: json: cannot unmarshal string into Go value of type repo.IndexFile`. using url 1.69/project/ABC result the same

Comment: If you're getting an error about "container in pod ..." then all of the Helm parts are correct; your Kubernetes cluster can't pull the image.  Do you need to authenticate to the repository at all?

Comment: @DavidMaze by authenticate you mean using username:password? i tried creating secret as kubernetes suggest to pull image from private repo. But it doesnt solve it. The issue is on minikube with self-signed certificate

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tried to create secret and follow this [discussion](https://github.com/helm/helm/issues/7519), but failed. until:

I used `kubectl describe` to check what is going on with my pod. Turns out it failed to pull image due to certificate is signed by unknown authority.

Found this discussion in [reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/kubernetes/comments/hsqjzk/it_fails_pulling_image_with_certificate_signed_by/), that showing minikube need to have a copy of the certificate inside its own directory. After providing the cert and restarting minikube, it works correctly.

[source](https://brokenco.de/2019/04/25/custom-certificates-minikube.html)

```sh
# create the dir if it is not exist
mkdir -p ~/.minikube/files/etc/ssl/certs

# copy the cert
cp ~/your.crt ~/.minikube/files/etc/ssl/certs/your-crt.pem
```